# Unordered List Item using FontAwesome as symbol how to prevent linebreak

Tags: css, list, font-awesome

Any chance i can prevent linebreak of an list item that uses a fontawesome icon?
alternatively let the second line that is caused by  the linebreak have the same indent....

if possible i don´t want to touch the html only  css

list-style-position doesnt work as the standard icon display is turned off

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
li{
   display: inline;
}
```

And, ff above doesn't work for you, then try this:

```
li{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your suggestion and i tried but was kind of overkill for what i wanted to achieve. i played  a bit and broke with my own rules not to touch the html, added  a span to the overhanging part  - just needed to give an display:block to this span and a litle margin to fit

Comment: @Arwed I used a span but used display:inline-flex without any margin.